# Javascript array modification

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that look like this:

```
[{year: "1920", count: 0}, {year: "1921", count: 2}, {year: "1925", count: 0}, {year: "1930", count: 21}, ....]
```

I want to, based on a starting year(ex. 1900) and an ending year(ex. 2000) fill up all years in between in the array with objects({year: -year-, count: 0}), so in the example above, the years between 1900 and 1920 would be added, and 1921-1925, and 1925-1930, and 1930-2000.

Has anyone had a similar problem and can help? Would be very much appreciated!

Edit: What I have tried so far is a simple for loop, checking in each iteration if the year is in the array .. But I feel like that is not a good and efficient way to solve it

Comment: It would be better if you let us know what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried a simple for loop, checking in each iteration if the year is in the array .. But I feel like that is not a good and efficient way to solve it .. (Updated the original question)  @Jejun

Comment: Add the code that you've tried and what you're having trouble with. Adding more specific example output will help as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first create an object from `current years` array and generate the new array while checking if the year present in that object:

```js
const presentYear = [{year: "1920", count: 0}, {year: "1921", count: 2}, {year: "1925", count: 0}, {year: "1930", count: 21}];

const presentYearObj = Object.fromEntries(presentYear.map(k=>[k.year, k]));

const allData = Array.from({length:101}, (_,i)=>presentYearObj[`${1900+i}`] || ({year:`${1900+i}`, count:0}));

console.log(allData);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arrs =
    [
        {year: "1920", count: 0},
        {year: "1921", count: 2},
        {year: "1925", count: 0},
        {year: "1930", count: 21}
    ]

let arr2 = arrs.map(it => {
    return +it.year
})

console.log(arr2)

for (let i = 1900; i < 2000; i++) {
    if (!arr2.includes(i)) {
        arrs.push({year: i + '', count: 0})
    }
}

console.log(arrs.length)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fillYears(from, to, existingArray) {
  
  let existingObject = {};
  existingArray.map(x => existingObject[x.year] = x.count);
  
  let yearsArray = [];
  for (let i = from; i <= to; i++) {
    yearsArray.push({ 
      year: i.toString(), 
      count: existingObject[i] || 0
    });
  }
  
  return yearsArray;
  
}

let arrYears = [
        { year: "1920", count: 0},
        { year: "1921", count: 5},
        { year: "1925", count: 0},
        { year: "1930", count: 10}
  ];

arrYears = fillYears(1900, 2000, arrYears);
console.log( arrYears );
```

This function creates a new array, completing the count values from the existing array.